# Primality testing when $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$ and $gcd(totient(n), (n-1)/2) = 1$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primality-test, legendre-symbol

Euler proved that if $n$ is prime, $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv \genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{a}{n}\pmod{n}$, which for primes is $1$ if $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $n$, $-1$ if $a$ is a non-quadratic residue mod n, and $0$ if $a\equiv 0\pmod{n}$. In fact, half of all bases a < n will be quadratic residues, and half will be non-quadratic.

When $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is odd (implying $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$), this means $(-a)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv -a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\pmod{n}$, so first half of bases $a$ will be the complement of the second half of bases $a$ mod $n$. If $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is instead even, the second half will be equal to the first half, reversed. The fermat primality test uses the fact that $a^{(n-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ for all $a$ not congruent to $0$ mod $n$, which implies these values should all be square roots of 1 mod $n$.

(Edit per comments) $1$ cannot have square roots mod $n$ which are not $1$ or $-1$ when $n$ is prime. However, if $n$ is composite and $gcd(totient(n),\frac{n-1}{2}) = 1$, except for the trivial case of $(-1)^k\equiv -1\pmod{n}$ for odd $k$, no base $a$ will satisfy $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\equiv -1 $ or $ 1\pmod{n}$ when $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. If any value is $1$, then its complement is $-1$, implying $n$ is prime. If the value isn't $1$ or $-1$, the number is composite.

This produces the primality test (only when $gcd(totient(n),\frac{n-1}{2}) = 1$, which implies $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$):

1. Choose any base $1 < a < n - 1$ ($2$ is the simplest) and compute $r = a^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \pmod n$
2. If $r\equiv -1 $ or $ 1\pmod{n}$, then $n$ is prime.
3. Otherwise, $n$ is composite.

In most cases, calculating $totient(n)$ to make use of this test is as hard as factoring which is more difficult than testing for primality in the first place. But certain number forms guarantee the condition, for instance $2p+1$ (and likely $2pq+1$, where $p$ and $q$ are sequential primes). In general, if $n = 2x+1$ and we can guarantee $gcd(totient(n), x) = 1$, this is a very fast way to determine if $n$ is prime or composite. This can also be achieved with a modified prime number sieve which also removes modulus where $p-1$ would divide $n-1$ (I do not yet have estimates on precisely what range of values of $n$ the condition would hold for given a set of primes this was applied to).

Edit: The post originally made the assumption this was true when $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$ generally, and has now been edited to use the more complete condition that $gcd(totient(n), (n-1)/2) = 1$.

Comment: When $n$ is prime, $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a field so $x^2\equiv1$ can’t have roots besides $\pm1$

Comment: Thanks! I thought it seemed right, just wasn't sure what the basis for it was.

Comment: Are you asserting that the only value of $a$ for which $a^{(n-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod{n}$, when $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, is $a\equiv -1\pmod{n}$, regardless of whether $n$ is prime or composite?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No. Basically if n is composite, no value for a should yield -1 except for the trivial a = n - 1, as the (n-1)/2 is odd and n - 1 is congruent to -1. And if n is prime, half the values will yield 1 and half will yield -1. So if you see -1, then n must be prime, and if you see 1, then -a will yield -1, then n must be prime. So you shouldn't see 1 or -1 on composites except for the trivial values.

Comment: The +/-1 on primes follows from it being a field as mentioned in comment above, so need to prove if n % 4 = 3 and n is composite, a^((n-1)/2) % n = -1 only when a % n = -1. I think this actually holds for n % 4 = 1 as well, we just can't use the presence of a 1 to prove primality or compositeness, since -a would also yield a 1 which could be a fermat liar.

Comment: So, I ask you if you are asserting that the only value of $a$ for which $a^{(n-1)/2}$ is $-1$ modulo $n$ is $a\equiv -1$, and you reply by saying "no", and then you **assert** that very thing. So which is it?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, the distinction I was making is that I assert that for composites but **not** primes.

Comment: Well, you're going to have to provide an actual proof of that assertion. Right now, I don't believe it.

Comment: Like I said, I don't have proof. just intuition and data. Here's the mathematica function I used, if the third value is 1 or n-1, PrimeQ seems to always return true, false when it's not:
powercalc[base_, mod_] := {PrimeQ[mod], mod, 
  PowerMod[base, (mod - 1)/2, mod]}

Comment: For example, $3^{4455}\equiv -1 \pmod {8911}$.  $8911$ is not prime, it is $7\times 19\times 67$.  $8911$ was not chosen randomly...it's the smallest Carmichael number of the form $4n+3$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, of course it would be a carmichael number. Testing it with base chosen as 2 confirms it's not prime though... will need to look more at the carmichael numbers

Comment: Just to say:  There aren't a lot of small Carmichael numbers $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: $n=2047$ and base $2$ is a counterexample. $n$ is of the desired form and the residue is $1$. However , $n$ is composite. So, a counterexample need not be a Carmichael number.

Comment: I have edited the post to show the correct condition needed for this test to be valid